# How to prevent NullPointerException in a Java Class in Domino agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino

My assumption is that, checking if the first document is null should be enough to prevent a nullexception error but that is not the case.

I cannot seem to find where the exception is coming from and how to prevent it.

**Below is the error log:**

```
Agent Manager: Agent printing: Create Report error:  null
Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.lang.NullPointerException
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.createReport(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
Agent Manager: Agent  error:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Below are the functions being called**

```
        private void createReport() {
        Integer qCount = 0;
        Document qDoc = null;
        ViewNavigator vNav = null;

        try {
            qView = currentDatabase.getView("RecsByRNo");
            qDoc = qView.getFirstDocument();
            vNav = qView.createViewNav();

            while (qDoc != null) {

                String qNo = qDoc.getItemValueString("RNo");
                String qType = qDoc.getItemValueString("EType");
                String qStatus = qDoc.getItemValueString("Status");
                String qBy = qDoc.getItemValueString("RBy");

                Document tmpReqDoc = qView.getNextDocument(qDoc);
                qDoc.recycle();
                qDoc = tmpReqDoc;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logErrors("Create Report error: ", e);

        } finally {
            try {
                qView.recycle();
                qDoc.recycle();
                vNav.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        agentLogger.LogAction("<<< Count: " + qCount + " >>>");
    }

    private void logErrors(String t, Exception e) {
        agentLogger.LogError(t + " " + e.getMessage());
        agentLogger.LogError(t + " " + e.getStackTrace().toString());
        System.out.println(t + " " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably is `currentDatabase` not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on the option „Compile Java code with debugging information“ in the agent properties to get the line number of the error in the Java stacktrace. This should give you some hints. currentDatabase might be null or the view does not exist.

Comment: Making changes to the database session did not rectify the issue, but turning on the debugging information shows the actual error. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on "compile Java code with debugging information" so you know where the error is